# Enums vs string constants c#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

So I have recently read a book specifically on Dependency Injection. In this book, somewhere, it states that enums are a code smell....

I wanted to get a general consensus from SO'ers. I need to design a rather large application with some central core classes, and am seeking assistance in terms design principles that fellow SO'ers would use in this instance, before committing myself to one way or the other making it very difficult to change afterwards.

```
public enum Foo
{
  LovelyFoo,
  TerribleFoo
}
```

OR

Using a static class with Contants

```
public static class Foo
{
    public const string LovelyFoo = nameof(LovelyFoo); //or "Lovely Foo";
    public const string TerribleFoo = nameof(TerribleFoo); // or "Terrible Foo";
}
```

Then Of course using it when required

```
Foo MyFoo = Foo.LovelyFoo;
```

OR

```
string MyFoo = Foo.LovelyFoo;
```

Comment: Have a look at this to get an idea about the context in which enums are better than strings. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/349146/c-is-it-better-to-use-string-or-an-enum-as-a-key

Comment: This is the first time I heared that "enums are a code smell", and this feels like *way* too general of a statement. Could you please elaborate on the reasons the book gives for that assessment?

Comment: "WARNING As a rule of thumb, enums are code smells and should be refactored
to polymorphic classes.8 However, they serve us well for this example."

Comment: While it's true that there *are* examples where enums are (ab)used where other constructs would be better, I'd still strongly disagree with the implied "**all** enums are a code smell". They do have their reasons to exist and to be used. The book even seems to make one point itself: sometimes it's just easier/faster. I love DI and use it almost everywhere, but one shouldn't forget YAGNI either. -- That said, forgoing enums in favour of "constant string collections" is *at least* just as "bad", probably worse. For example: how do you enumerate all possible strings of one "collection"?

Comment: For enums it's as "easy" as `Enum.GetValues(typeof(TheEnum)).Cast<TheEnum>()`

Comment: Hi Corak, Yes - I use DI pretty much everywhere - I also use Lightinject as my go to DI Container. I guess to answer your question regarding a "collection" - then I guess you could reflection in a somehwat similar sense to your example by - var Collection = typeof(Foo).GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Just because something can be abused doesn't mean its bad to use.
2. you gave no realistic use cases, and just foo examples its hard to tell if this smells or not.
3. enums are good for tightly bound sets of things, days of the week for instance.

   - Were there is a legitimate use for switch statements
   - Where the set doesn't change and is ingrained.
   - Where (and this is circular i know) enums make sense

Let constants be constants, let enums be enums. But if you find your self wanting to use lots of enums and switches, then this is probably crying out for generics or polymorphic. Just because they look neat and typed and wonderful doesn't mean your code should be full of them.

Lastly, Run the Microsoft test over your use cases. That's to say, what would Microsoft do, where in the BCL have you seen this example, is it common, does Microsoft use them like this. Although this is no saving grace, if you find your self writing weird and wonderful structures that are unpredictable and no-one else has seen, then you are probably doing something wrong